# Jquery html() not showing textbox value

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to copy some html around a page and I wanted to use the jquery html() to do it. It worked well until I wanted to get a value from a user entered text box and the value hadn't copied.

I looked in firebug and the entered data wasn't shown in the value field of the textbox.

How do I get around this?

Comment: The user-edited `value` is a *property*, not an attribute. You have to use jQuery's `.val()` method for each input field to obtain the value.

Comment: do you have code sample? hard to *guess* without seeing the code. I kinda suspect the `$.html()` function is not meant for what you're trying to do tho..

Comment: I am trying to retain the form state while moving the html from one node to another. This doesn't seem possible!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use `.val()` to do this:

```
var textareaText = $('#mytextarea').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting confused between jquery `.text()` and `.val()` functions

`.text()` Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants.

`.val()` Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

check this not sure if you are looking for this ?  http://jsfiddle.net/MMJRk/1/

Comment: Just as a meta-comment, SO answers are much better when they actually include your code, not just a jsFiddle link. If the jsFiddle code is too long or complex, include a few relevant pieces and/or an explanation of what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: sure sir, I taut it would be easy to verify though, I will keep this in mind though. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it impossible to get value using html(), use .val() instead

b.t.w if it is important for you to preserve the line breaks in html format you can do the following:

```
var textareaHtmlVal = $('#text_area_id').val().replace(/\n/gi,'<br />');
```